# Can I reply to a HTTP Request Before I've Finished Receiving it?

Tags: http

**Clarification:** I'm writing a HTTP server in C++. I know exactly how much data I've received and I'm parsing the HTTP request in chunks. So, it's possible for me to know what the method is before I've received the entire request.

Consider the following scenario: I receive a HTTP request with the method set to 'DO_WORK'. This isn't supported (just an example), and I should reply with a 405 (method not supported). However, how soon can I do so?

Should I wait until I have received the entire request before I send a response?

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is a technical reason prohibiting it, you can generally send the reply as soon as you are ready to, as the client will not read it until it has finished sending its request in full.  You do, however, have to read the full request unless you disconnect after sending the reply.

Comment: Thanks Remy, appreciate your reply. Assuming that it's an appropriate option I think that 'disconnect after sending the reply' is the best design for me to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) to intercept the call and return what you want.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, see the clarification above.

Comment: @LiamM might be worth taking a look at https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/mongoose.c then

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache then you can set the LIMIT directive:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit

I don't know if it will understand DO_WORK, but you can try this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/333610/apache-and-custom-http-method

If you only want to limit it to certain methods then do a limitexcept:

```
<Directory .../.../>
        ...
        <LimitExcept GET POST>
              Order deny,allow
              Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
   </Directory>
```

I haven't tested this though.

Also you don't know how much of a message is passed with networking. If it's smart the server will only send the header first then parts of the body later. But if the message is small it might send the header and the message all at once.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I made a quick edit to my question (first paragraph).