# How to run PHP early before HTTP request content finished?

Tags: php, http, httpresponse, put, chunked

I'm creating some specific application in PHP that receive data from clients and process it.
Sometimes the data sent by client can be significantly large or unknown length.

So I want to ask if it possible to make PHP start processing data before client finish uploading?

Here what I'm looking to:

From PHP docs it is possible to use PUT method and receive content via php://input
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php
I'm planning on using PUT method with chunked transfer encoding.

but I just try sending PUT method to phpinfo.php (You know what inside.)
and intentionally not sent last chunk. (zero length chunk)
The PHP doesn't response unless I complete the request.
(That's not what I expect from PUT method it should has some kind of pros.
If it unable to start PHP early I rather use ordinary POST method.)

And according to this topic
[Can I reply to a HTTP Request Before I've Finished Receiving it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419096/)
I don't think early response from PHP will break HTTP.
(Don't worry about the client I write it myself.)

Note: Breaking data into many request is not an option because in order to process the data there are some memory/objects that cant be shared among multiple PHP instances. (even with memory table in MySQL.)

Comment: Are you using Apache or Windows or another server? I am not 100% certain, but I don't believe the PHP interpreter is called by the server typically until the request has been received and parsed by the server. In the question you linked, the asker was building a custom server software, and many responses refer to built-in Apache functionality rather than other processes like PHP.

Comment: I tried it on Apache server.
Thanks for the info.
Then do you know the the pros of PUT method?

Comment: I would also check to make sure the output isn't simply being buffered until the request is finished sending.  It might only look like PHP is not executing.

Comment: PUT should be used when the contents of the target URL are being replaced by the message body.  POST should be used when the content refers to a subordinate resource of the target URL.  (POST /comments, PUT /comments/52365)

Comment: Additionally, many clients won't display returned values from the server until the request has been sent.

Comment: @rich I wait long enough so that I'm sure if it execute it will be finished. About PUT/POST you mentioned I think that's the original goal when HTTP was designed the nowadays use is different; PUT may not use to upload file anymore as you can see even PHP not populate PUT content in $_FILE like uploading in POST. (at least in my opinion)

Comment: @Wige In my test I use a mere TCP client (not HTTP).

Comment: PUT can certainly be used to upload files.  The limitation you are talking about is a PHP thing.  It's been widely used for a long time in WebDAV, for instance, and there are Apache modules to automatically handle PUT-ting resources just like you GET them.  In PHP, you can use PUT by using file_get_contents("php://input") when $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is PUT.